# How to convert a UNIX time in milliseconds to POSIXlt in R?

Tags: r, datetime, unix-timestamp

I'm trying to parse the value

```
1454181695067-0800
```

As a datetime object in R. This value is milliseconds since epoch.

If I truncate the timezone and the milliseconds part of the value I can parse, i.e.

```
> as.POSIXlt(1454181695, origin = "1970-01-01")
[1] "2016-01-30 11:21:35 PST"
```

However, is it possible to do it all in one function call, which includes the milliseconds and handles the **-0800** portion correctly?

I'd prefer to do it with the default R functionality.

Comment: What does the "-0800" mean?

Comment: @Spacedman: it's likely the timezone offset from UTC.

Answer (score 1):

With your timestamp as a character:

```
x="1454181695067-0800"
```

Then split it with `read.fwf` and construct:

```
> bits = read.fwf(textConnection(x),widths=c(10,3,1,2,2))
> as.POSIXlt(bits$V1+bits$V2/1000, origin="1970-01-01") + ifelse(bits$V3=="-",-1,1)* (bits$V4*60*60+bits$V5*60)
[1] "2016-01-30 11:21:35 GMT"
```

Although the milliseconds don't show, they are there. If you call that thing `t0` then:

```
> as.numeric(t0 - as.integer(t0))
[1] 0.06699991
```

Comment: Use `options(digits.secs=3)` to show milliseconds when printing POSIXt objects.